# Optimized way to join two collections in Marklogic and get the result

Tags: marklogic, cts

Example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $Schema_Student in collection ("Student"),  $Schema_Staff in collection ("Staff")
where ($Schema_Student/Student/Pincode = $Schema_Staff/Schema_Staff/Pincode)
return document-uri($Staff)
```

Output will be document URIs from "Staff" Collection.

Data details:
If I have 10 document-uri with the Pincode "560049" in the "Student" collection and 10 document-uri with the Pincode "560049" in the "Staff" collection:

- My expected output is 10 document-uri, but the output of this query is returning 100 document-uri.
- This query does a lot of things internally by joining
- If I have 10 document-uri of "Student" and 10 of "Staff" collections,
- The result of joining will give you 10*10 = 100 document URIs, which is an unnecessary join.

Do we have an optimized solution for joining two collections?

Note: Condition fields don't have the path range index.

Any suggestions?

I tried the CTS query, but it needs to have a path range index. But for my requirement, fields can be without path range index.

Comment: Can you post one example data from `Student` and `Staff` collection. For me if a document can have only one Pincode, it is returning 10 results (not 100). It returns 100 results if I get rid of the where condition.

Comment: Your query doesn't specifically filter the student+staff who has Pincode 560049. So, if there were 100 staffs in your collection and all of them had a matching student (with same `Pincode`) then your Xquery (and my suggestion) will all return 100 results

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code (which will result in lesser loop execution).

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $staff in collection("Staff")
where ($staff/Schema_Staff/Pincode = collection("Student")/Student/Pincode)
return document-uri($staff)
```

One disadvantage in the above approach is `collection("Staff")/Schema_Staff/Pincode` is executed once for every document under `collection("Student")`. I would prefer the following:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $student-pincodes := collection("Student")/Student/Pincode
for $staff in collection("Staff")
where ($staff/Schema_Staff/Pincode = $student-pincodes)
return document-uri($staff)
```

Comment: Using a `cts` query without index is probably going to behave the same using `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you could look to achieve this without range-indexes, but without an index you will be reading all of the docs in the collection, so it may not perform as well and may hit Expanded Tree Cache limits if the collections are really large.

That being said, one option is to retrieve the set of `Pincode` values from the Student collection and then use them to query for the URIs of the documents in the Staff collection that have those same `Pincode` values:

```
let $student-pincodes := collection("Student")/Student/Pincode/string()
return 
  cts:uris("",(), cts:and-query(( 
    cts:collection-query("Staff"), 
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("Schema_staff"), 
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Pincode"), $student-pincodes) 
  )))
```